# how to get value of dynamically added textbox in gridview. getting an error that Reference object has value of nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have added Textbox like 
Protected Sub gvReconciliation_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvReconciliation.RowDataBound

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim txtRemarks As New TextBox()
        txtRemarks.ID = "txtRemarks"
        txtRemarks.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("Remarks").ToString()
        e.Row.Cells(10).Controls.Add(txtRemarks)


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: proper explain your problem?

Comment: I have added one textbox in dynamic grid on Row Data bound of that grid, and after on save button click, when I try to fetch value of textbox, I am getting error that Reference object has value of nothing

Comment: show your aspx page Remarks Field use aspx page?

Comment: Just a hint: your ID has to be unique. If your table has more than one row, you will run into problems

Comment: Where is your code for the save button click? That is likely where the problem is. Also, does each row have a save button or only one for the entire grid?